# While loop doesnt work?

Tags: c, list, while-loop, stack

Few days ago we wrote this code in class and teacher tried to explain it, most of us didn't understand. I'm almost fully understanding it by now, but why the second while in main doesnt work? It should output a name before poping it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct STK_S{
    char name[100];
    struct STK_S *next;
}STK;
int push(STK **ppS, STK *pD);
int pop(STK **ppS, STK *pD);

int main(){
    STK *pS, d;
    pS = NULL;
    while (1){
        printf_s("Ime ");
        gets_s(d.name, 100);
        if (d.name[0] == 0)
            break;
        push(&pS, &d);
    }
    while (pop(&pS, &d))
        printf_s("\n%s", d.name);
    return 0;
}

int push(STK **ppS, STK *pD){
    STK *pt;
    pt = (STK *)malloc(sizeof(STK));
    if (pt == NULL)
        return 0;
    *pt = *pD;
    pt->next = *ppS;
    *ppS = pt;
    return 1;
}

int pop(STK **ppS, STK *pD){
    STK *pt;
    if (*ppS == NULL){
        printf("Empty stack.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    *pD = **ppS;
    pt = *ppS;
    *ppS = pt->next;
    free(pt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: return 1 at the end of pop().

Comment: Yes I copied the right code, I knew there was something working with these returns being the same (kinda). Thanks guys. Works now.

Comment: `NULL` is the null-***pointer*** literal. That you do not want to return form a function returning `int`.

Comment: BTW, no need to cast the result from `malloc()` as you do C and not C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pop` returns `NULL` or `0`, which both convert to `false`. So the loop runs not a single time.

Comment: Yes I changed the second return to 1 and it works now, thanks! But I wonder why it even works? If it frees the memory of that element, how it gets printed?

Comment: Probably luck. Accessing the memory after it's freed is _undefined behavior_; in reality, released memory tends to keep it's data for a while (until it's reused), so the print still finds it there.

Comment: @JustSteve: It gets copied and with this saved here: `*pD = **ppS;` *before* the memory where `*ppS` points to is freed.